# How to prevent N+1 queries when fetching ancestors with Django Treebeard?

Tags: django, django-models, django-treebeard

We are using Django Treebeard's materialized path to model an organizational hierarchy as follows:

[image: Organizational Hierarchy Example]

Now each node in the organizational tree can have multiple tasks:

```
class Organization(MP_Node):
    node_order_by = ['name']
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Task(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description= models.TextField()
```

**Given a list of tasks, we wish to include the full organizational path of each task in the result. How can we achieve this without the need for N+1 queries?**

Expected result for organization Factory 1 could be for example:

| Task name | Organization Path |
| --- | --- |
| Task 1 | MyCompany/Factory 1/Maintenance |
| Task 2 | MyCompany/Factory 1/Operations |
| Task 3 | MyCompany/Factory 1 |
| Task 4 | MyCompany/Factory 1/Operations |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django-treebeard stores the materialized path in the `path` column as a string like this: `000100020005002I`. In this example, the following rows are its ancestors (given the default step length of 4):

```
0001
00010002 
000100020005  
000100020005002I
```

What django-treebeard does is to split a page's path into the aforementioned bits in Python and then perform a database query like so:

```py
Organization.objects.filter(path__in=['0001', '00010002', '000100020005'])`
```

To avoid the *n+1 query problem*, we need to avoid splitting the path in Python and perform the ancestor lookup in the database via a subquery.

Pattern matching can be used to see if an ancestor's path is contained in the child's path: `00010002` matches `000100020005002I` when the candidate's path is used as a pattern for the path of the organization in question:

```sql
000100020005002I LIKE 00010002%  --- equals true
```

```sql
SELECT  
  organization.path, 
  ARRAY(
   SELECT 
     name 
   FROM
     organization o_ 
   WHERE 
     organization.path LIKE o_.path || '%' 
  )
FROM 
  organization
```

| organization.path | array |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | {root} |
| 00010001 | {root, org_a} |
| 00010002 | {root, org_b} |
| 000100020001 | {root, org_b, org_b1} |

Django doesn't provide an out-of-the-box solution for switching the arguments around in a `.filter(path__startswith='pattern')` lookup (as is required in our case here). That's why I'm using the RawSQL expression.

```py
>>> from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

>>> orgs = Organization.objects.annotate(
    ancestors=RawSQL(
        """
        ARRAY(
          SELECT name FROM organization o_ 
          WHERE organization.path LIKE o_.path || '%%'
        ) 
        FROM organization
        """,
        params=[],
    )
)

>>> orgs[0].ancestors
['Root', "Org 1", "Org 2", "Org 3"]
```